# Converting dataframe column from hhmmss to hh:mm:ss in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

As my time-series dataframe is in the time format hhmmss, I can't plot it against my data without it skipping, for instance, 000059 -> 000100 at the end of every minute. [Data Head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ9T4.png)

When I search for solutions, they all show conversion of hh:mm:ss to seconds, but my time is in hhmmss not hh:mm:ss.

I've tried converting hhmmss to a string, defining the hh, mm and ss separately using their index, converting to an integer and then converting hh and mm to seconds, then adding them all back together to get hhmmss in seconds.

```
data = pd.read_csv("CONT  65.754 248.750 20011120 GEODETIC nT17280", sep =" " )
data['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(data['TIME'], format = '%H%M%S')
data['secs'] = (data.TIME.dt.hour*3600 + data.TIME.dt.minute*60) + data.TIME.dt.second

time_sec = data['secs']
X_Value = data['X']

plt.plot(time_sec, X_Value)
```

When I try this, I get the error:
'time data 4 does not match format '%H%M%S' (match)'

How could I convert my time column in the format hhmmss, to be in the format of seconds?
Many thanks :)

Comment: Please add your sample data with question

Comment: could you please clarify what you mean by "jumping"? and as @NIKUNJKOTHIYA commented, please add exemplary data.

Comment: By jumping I meant skipping and I've added a picture example of my head(). Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative approach you could accept the integers from read_csv and convert directly to seconds:

```
data = pd.read_csv("CONT  65.754 248.750 20011120 GEODETIC nT17280", sep =" " )
def func(x):
    s1 = x%100
    s2 = (x//100)%100
    s3 = x//10000
    return s3*3600 + s2*60 + s1


df['secs'] = df['TIME'].map(func)
```

Answer (score 0):

A pandas Timestamp object is an internal binary storage format not as you suggest. If your column TIME is of type DateTime /TimeStamp then you can simply create a new column by converting the time to seconds and then use that for plotting:

```
df['secs'] = (df.TIME.dt.hour*60 + df.TIME.dt.minute)*60 + df.TIME.dt.second
```

Comment: After trying this, I get the error: 'Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values'. I think because I am in the format hhmmss not hh:mm:ss, pandas can't differentiate between the hours, minutes and seconds. Part of my problem is converting from hhmmss to hh:mm:ss so I can do this.

Comment: This means that your DF does not have values of type datetime. The first thing you should do it find out the actual type using `print(df['TIME'].dtype)` and go from there. To repeat the point Pandas keeps datetime objects in it's own internal format not in various formats defined by the user.

Comment: Hey, I've changed the code to convert it to a pandas datetime object and now I'm having a new error (I've updated my question). Going back to my original question, do you have any suggestions as to how I could plot my time series in seconds when my data is in the format of hhmmss?

Comment: Your problem seems to be that your string from the CSV is not in the format assumed in your format statement. You should use `print(data['TIME'])` immediately after the read_csv statement and check if it is really fully compatible with your format.

Comment: Okay I've done that and it's essentially in the hhmmss format but without displaying any zeroes so instead of 000004, and 000436 I have 4 and 436 respectively. This is despite my original dataset containing the zeroes. What part of the code can I change to keep the zeroes as from the dataset?

Comment: It seems that your values are not strings but interpreted as integers hence dropping all leading zeros. You can convert to strings in the 6 digit format (filling out with 0) using: `df['TIME'] = df['TIME'].map(lambda x: f'{x:0>6}')`